# Build submitted for AppStore but only seen on TestFlight

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

After getting confused about the process Apple has set for submitting apps, I am posting my question here.

I have uploaded a new build of my app to the iTunes connect and the confusing part is that I am seeing it under "TestFlight" section (iTunesconnect -> My Apps -> TestFlight).

However, when I select the "App Store" tab, I cannot see the build on the list.

[image]
Is this normal, does the build need to pass through TestFlight before I will be able to submit it for AppStore review? am I missing something?

Comment: Is there a n "add a version or platform" button? Have you tried going to incognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new app version and add testflight build in that version.

click on this button:-

[image]

Comment: Clicking that will add a new version if you want to submit a new build to the App Store. Just try it!